# Can't move vertices and bones anymore

Tags: objects

I think I made some mistakes and now I can't move my stuff anymore.

I uploaded a blend file so you may could tell me what I have done wrong and next time I will be able to fix the problem by myself.

Link to blend file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7l1tb5v2g0lpyzs/character.blend?dl=0

Comment: Try using shift+tab to disable snapping, not sure if this is your problem without more details in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your file. As @Denis stated: You activated *Snapping*, the little orange horseshoe. Just disable it using Shift+Tab, and you can move the bones around again.